# How to use configuration value in virtual fields definition?

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to use configuration value in my virtual fields, something like it:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'allow_modification' => ' CASE WHEN publish_date IS NULL OR publish_date + interval \''.Configure::read('Setting.app.allow_modification').'\' > NOW() THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END'
    );
```

but it doesn't work. I know it's related to PHP but is there some way how to  solve and modify `virtualFields` it in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `virtualFields` in your `Model` constructor (see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases)):

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
        $this->virtualFields['allow_modification'] = 'CASE WHEN publish_date IS NULL OR publish_date + interval \''.Configure::read('Setting.app.allow_modification').'\' > NOW() THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END' ;
    }
}
```